# Public Folders not accessible to Outlook clients

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook, public-folders

I've got a problem at the moment with my Exchange 2010 Server's Public Folders database - we had a VM issue over the weekend during some networking work and the Public Folders have been inaccessible since.

[image: Example of Error.]

The main Mail Store was also inaccessible, but that was due to the RPC service on the CAS stopping - restarting that service recovered it.

I've tried dismounting the Public Folder database and remounting it, but that has made no difference.

I've also worked through the tutorials like this one - http://blog.bruteforcetech.com/archives/766 - but all the data is correct in ADSIEdit.﻿

I've also worked through this Spiceworks thread and it doesn't fix anything - https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/170165-exchange-2010-public-folder-issue.

The Public Folders open fine in Public Folder Management Console.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it's accessible from OWA ?

Comment: Yes, they are. So it's a client issue?

I have removed my Outlook profile in Control Panel > Mail and re-created it and it hasn't solved anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by restarting the DB server.

I wasn't aware that an Exchange DB server still relied on IIS (a cursory glance in IISAdmin showed just the Default Site, so I guess I assumed it wasn't used) and as I was just restarting the plethora of Microsoft Exchange services, I was missing the problem.